# Login page is not working proprly and how to set session

Tags: php, html, css

```js
<?php
session_Start();
if (isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
{
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "mysite";
   
   
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  
   
   if ($conn->connect_error)
   
   
  {
      die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
  }
 else
{    
 $result1 = "SELECT userid, password FROM user WHERE username = '$username' And password = '$password'";
 $queryResult = $conn->query($result1);
 }
 
 if ($queryResult > 0)
 { 
 
  
  
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
  header("location: home.php");
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
 }
}
?>
```

```css
<style>
.header{
width:100%;
background-color:#00adff;
float:left;
color:white;
    padding: 1%;
}
.rightChuck{
float:right;
width:18%;
}
.menu{
float:left;
padding:5%;
}
#title
{
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}
body{
margin:0px !important;
}
h1{
margin: 0px !important;
}
#main
{
text-align:left;
}
#content{
    
 margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    bottom: 100;
    left: 100;
    right: 100;
    background: white;
 border: 5px solid green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
 
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Mysite.com</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div id="title">
<h1>Mysite.com</h1>
</div>
<div class="rightChuck">
<div class="menu">
<a href="login.php">LOGIN </a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
<a href="register.php">REGISTER</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div style="float:left;width:100%;padding:left:10px;">
<h2>LOGIN</h2>
</div>
<div id="content">
<center>
<form name="form" method="post">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
<tr><th ><h3>USERNAME</h3></th><td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"  size="20" id="textbox" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><h3>PASSWORD</h3></th><td><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"name="password"  size="20" id="textbox" required /></td></tr>
</td>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="LOGIN" value="LOGIN" id="buttondesign" />
<br />
<br />

</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

this login page not working properly,the right way is,when i click login button its go to check username and password from databse,if username and password is correctly,its username and user id stored in session ,its go to home page,else username and password its wrong,its come error message.but this code is contain some error like i click login button its go to home page,not check user name and password,then session is not stored.

Comment: is session_start(); not session_Start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Mysite.com</title>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div id="title">
<h1>Mysite.com</h1>
</div>
<div class="rightChuck">
<div class="menu">
<a href="login.php">LOGIN </a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
<a href="register.php">REGISTER</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div style="float:left;width:100%;padding:left:10px;">
<h2>LOGIN</h2>
</div>
<div id="content">
<center>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
<tr><th ><h3>USERNAME</h3></th><td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"  size="20" id="textbox" required /></td></tr>
<tr><th><h3>PASSWORD</h3></th><td><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"  size="20" id="textbox" required /></td></tr>
</td>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="LOGIN" value="LOGIN" id="buttondesign" />
<br />
<br />

</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
<?php
session_Start();
if (isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
{
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "mysite";
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())      
    {

          die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
     }
    else
        {   

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];


        $sql="SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `user` WHERE `username`= $username AND `password`=$password";

        if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
          {
          // Return the number of rows in result set
          $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($rowcount > 0)
                { 

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
                    header("location: home.php");
                }
                else
                {

                    echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
                }
            }

        }
    //echo $rowcount;


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

put action in form

```
<form name="form" method="post">
```

to

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="login.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have sessions_start on home page too:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Try adding the username in your SELECT query.

```
$result1 = "SELECT userid, username, password FROM user WHERE username = '$username' And password = '$password'";
```

And if you want to store the the user id too you need:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "s" in "start" in "session_start()" needs to be in lower case.

```
session_Start(); // This would not initiate the session 

session_start(); // This would initiate the session
```

Due to this the session is never created.

Fixing this should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_Start();
if (isset($_POST['LOGIN']))
{
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "mysite";
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if ($conn->connect_error)
      {
       die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }
    else
    {    
    $result1 = "SELECT userid, password FROM user WHERE username = '$username' And password = '$password'";
       $queryResult= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($queryResult); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row
    }
        if ($count == 1 && $row['password'] == $password) {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        } 
        else {
            $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
        }
}
?>
```